# Activity finished after changing locale

Tags: android, locale, activity-finish, onconfigurationchanged

I have `Activity A` and called from it `Activity B`.
In manifest Activity A has configChanges  `android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"`.

In Activity A 
 - for changing locale

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    res.updateConfiguration(newConfig, null);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

- for starting Activity B

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
      startActivity(intent);

If I start Activity A and change locale all is working fine.
But if I try to start Activity A, then start Activity B and after that go to Activity A and change locale, `Activity A will not be restarted, it will be destroyed`.
How can I prevent Activity A from being destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

Add the flag [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to your Intent. It will reorder an existing Activity from the stack if it is already running.

Comment: In Activity A 
 - for changing locale

 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
 {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  Resources res = this.getResources();
  res.updateConfiguration(newConfig, null);
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

- for starting Activity B

 Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
  startActivity(intent);